# Where can i find Icon Composer on Mac?

Tags: macos

I am trying to locate Icon Composer, which was supposedly downloaded as part of Xcode, however I can't find it, neither in applications nor with the spotlight.

Any ideas where it might be, or if I have to download it separately? If so, where from? I tried looking for it in the App Store, but nothing found.

Edit: I am using Xcode 4.4.1 if that helps.

Answer (score 18):

Icon Composer isn't supported by Apple these days, and one of the reasons is that Icon Composer doesn't allow for working with Retina Displays.

The replacement is a clunky command line tool named "`iconutil`".  It probably gets installed as part of the "Command Line tools for Xcode" download.

You need to create your icons as PNG's, put them into a folder (which will be called an `.iconset`) and then run the "`iconutil`" tool on that folder to create an "`.icns`" file.

[This related question has a useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770806/why-doesnt-icon-composer-2-4-support-the-1024x1024-size-icon-any-more), and [it points to this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW3). Once you get the hang of it though, the process of creating icons becomes straightforward.

Answer (score 7):

I have it for that version of Xcode in /Applications/Development.  If you don't have it, run Xcode and select the menu item "Xcode->Open Developer Tool->More Developer Tools..." and look for a graphics-related download.

Comment: Tested with OSX Mavericks and XCode 5 - Bang on!

Comment: Tested with OSX 10.9.4 and XCode 5.1.1 - Bang on!

Comment: Still available for download, but Icon Composer cannot be opened on Mojave

Answer (score 5):

Philip is right but here is a clarification, Icon Composer is still available. In XCode press the XCode menu > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools...

In the web site that appears you need to search for "Graphics Tools" and download the dmg file with the same name (around 120 MB). It will contain the Icon Composer app previously distributed with XCode.

Comment: Looks promising; Apple's Icon Composer auto-resizes images to fit the desired resolution; it would be nice if yours did as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to another newer github version Icon Compositor 2x - which also does 1024, so Retina resolution.
Here is the Github Repository:
https://github.com/lemonmojo/IconComposer2x

In the following [link for the original Icon Composer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW3) it says "Note: There is no longer a 1024x1024 size. That’s replaced by 512x512@2x."

The newer github version called Icon Compositor 2x does 1024 straight